# Update value in Kivy (Python) widget

Tags: python, kivy

I'd like to display numeric values coming from a sensor (Tinkerforge ambient light sensor) in Kivy widgets. Unfortunately the variable 'illuminance' doesn't seem to change at all and the widgets display '0'.'illuminance' seems to update nicely and gets printed on the console. What am I doing wrong?

```
import kivy
import random
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

from tinkerforge.ip_connection import IPConnection
from tinkerforge.brick_dc import BrickDC
from tinkerforge.bricklet_ambient_light import BrickletAmbientLight

HOST = "localhost"          # Tinkerforge IP and port
PORT = 4223
UID = "uM9"             # sensor ID

illuminance = 0

ipcon = IPConnection()          # Create IP connection
al = BrickletAmbientLight(UID, ipcon)   # Create device object
ipcon.connect(HOST, PORT)       # Connect to brickd

class TimerTink:
    def tinker(self):
        illuminance = al.get_illuminance()  #read sensor value
        print(illuminance)

class TinkerApp(App):
    def build(self):
        main_layout = BoxLayout(padding=10, orientation="vertical")
        for i in range(2):
            h_layout = BoxLayout(padding=10)
            for i in range(2):
                lbl = Label(text=str(illuminance),)
                h_layout.add_widget(lbl)
            main_layout.add_widget(h_layout)
        event = Clock.schedule_interval(TimerTink.tinker, 1/2)
        return main_layout

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = TinkerApp()
    app.run()
```

Finally it's working, thanks to @YOSHI 's suggestions:

```
import kivy
import random
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

from tinkerforge.ip_connection import IPConnection
from tinkerforge.brick_dc import BrickDC
from tinkerforge.bricklet_ambient_light import BrickletAmbientLight

HOST = "localhost"          # Tinkerforge IP and port
PORT = 4223
UID = "uM9"             # sensor ID

illuminance = 0

ipcon = IPConnection()          # Create IP connection
al = BrickletAmbientLight(UID, ipcon)   # Create device object
ipcon.connect(HOST, PORT)       # Connect to brickd


class TinkerApp(App):

    def build(self):
        i = 0
        main_layout = BoxLayout(padding=10, orientation="vertical")
        h_layout = FloatLayout(size=(300,300))
        self.label = Label(text=str(illuminance),pos=(i*100, i*100),size_hint = (.1,.1))
        h_layout.add_widget(self.label)
        main_layout.add_widget(h_layout)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.timer, 0.1)

        return main_layout

    def timer(self, dt):
        illuminance = al.get_illuminance()  #read sensor value
        self.label.text = str(illuminance)
        print(str(illuminance))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = TinkerApp()
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 1):

The function 'tinker' in the TimeTink class takes 2 arguments: self and dt

```
def tinker(self,dt):
    illuminance = al.get_illuminance()  #read sensor value
    print(illuminance)
```

or you change the line where you call the method to sth. like this:

```
event = Clock.schedule_interval(lambda dt: TimerTink.tinker, 1/2)
```

for more info visit the doc for [kivy.clock](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.clock.html).

Edit: (maybe this works)

```
import kivy
import random
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout


from tinkerforge.ip_connection import IPConnection
from tinkerforge.brick_dc import BrickDC
from tinkerforge.bricklet_ambient_light import BrickletAmbientLight

HOST = "localhost"          # Tinkerforge IP and port
PORT = 4223
UID = "uM9"             # sensor ID

illuminance = 0

ipcon = IPConnection()          # Create IP connection
al = BrickletAmbientLight(UID, ipcon)   # Create device object
ipcon.connect(HOST, PORT)       # Connect to brickd


main_layout = BoxLayout(padding=10, orientation="vertical")
for i in range(2):
    h_layout = BoxLayout(padding=10)
    for i in range(2):
        lbl = Label(text=str(illuminance),)
        h_layout.add_widget(lbl)
    main_layout.add_widget(h_layout)
def tinker(self):
    illuminance = al.get_illuminance()  #read sensor value
    lbl.text = str(illuminance)
    print(illuminance)

class TinkerApp(App):
    def build(self):
        event = Clock.schedule_interval(tinker, 1/2)
        return main_layout

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = TinkerApp()
    app.run()
```

Comment: Tried both. When I add 'dt' as a second argument, I get this error: TypeError: tinker() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Comment: When adding 'lambda dt' to the clock method, I get nothing. The window appears with value 0 and nothing on the terminal. I am very confused. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your Button(btn) text doesn't update when you update the sensor value

Comment: Apologies, I should have clarified: the buttons might as well be labels (I will update the code), they only have to display text. At the moment the main view is not updated therefor the values displayed don't change.

Comment: In the function 'tinker' you call every .5 second you need to add a line where you update the button/label text you can do this with ids.

Comment: you don't actually need to use ids because you don't use a kv file

Comment: Working, thanks to your suggestion, see update. Millions of thanks